# Extending a base tpl file and editing the body of it in bottle

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I am familiar with flask, and trying hands on bottle module. I wanted to have a single base.tpl file which can have an editable body and the other tpl files could extend this base file and edit in its body to change the content. Like in flask, using jinja, we could use `{% block bodyContent %}{% endblock %}` and insert the html body content later when needed. How can we achieve the same with bottle module?

Comment: check https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/20 if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Bottle [comes with jinja2 support](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html?highlight=jinja#templates), out of the box. Here's a toy example, just to illustrate. Note that you may prefer to use Bottle's `jinja2_view` rather than return a template directly.

```
from bottle import jinja2_template

app = Bottle()

home_template = '''
{{greeting}} - Thanks for stopping by.
'''

app.route('/')
def home():
    return jinja2_template(home_template, greeting='Hello!')
```

You can find examples of more advanced usage [here](https://buxty.com/b/2013/12/jinja2-templates-and-bottle/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually bottle comes with this solution built into it's own template engine.

https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#template-functions

**include**(sub_template, **variables)
Render a sub-template with the specified variables and insert the resulting text into the current template. The function returns a dictionary containing the local variables passed to or defined within the sub-template:

```
% include('header.tpl', title='Page Title')
Page Content
% include('footer.tpl')
```

**rebase**(name, **variables)
Mark the current template to be later included into a different template. After the current template is rendered, its resulting text is stored in a variable named base and passed to the base-template, which is then rendered. This can be used to wrap a template with surrounding text, or simulate the inheritance feature found in other template engines:

```
% rebase('base.tpl', title='Page Title')
<p>Page Content ...</p>
```

This can be combined with the following base.tpl:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{title or 'No title'}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{!base}}
</body>
</html>
```